# How I can get the first data using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have some test data file test.txt:

```
{
  "type": "home",
  "number": "212 555-1234"
}
{
  "type": "fax",
  "number": "646 555-4567"
}
```

I try get the first number:

```
jq .number test.txt
```

But it get all number.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As you see, by default, jq reads the entire input stream.  The -n command-line option turns this behavior off, so one (efficient) solution would be:

```
jq -n 'input.number' test.txt
```

If your jq does not have `input`, then now would be an excellent time to upgrade; if that is not possible:

```
jq -s '.[0].number' test.txt
```